# Как сделать просвечивание через текст свечением, исходящим от курсора?

Tags: javascript, html, css, дизайн

Нужно, чтобы был чёрный фон и белый текст. Также, требуется наличие цветного свечения, похожего на радиальный градиент. Оно должно просвечиваться через текст, но чёрный фон должен находиться поверх свечения. То есть, это цветное свечение должно быть видно только через текст при подведении к нему на некоторое расстояние курсора, а фоном этот градиент должен игнорироваться. К сожалению, не имею возможности предоставить пример, поскольку его нет. Не знаю, насколько понятно объяснил, поэтому заранее извиняюсь за непонимание и глупость моей формулировки. Буду очень рад любым ответам. Спасибо!

Comment: скиншот добавить бы

Comment: К сожалению, как указано в моём вопросе, примера нет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Исходя из описания, должно получиться следующее:

```js
document.querySelector('.wrapper').addEventListener('mousemove', function(ev) {
  this.style.setProperty('--y', `${ev.pageY - this.clientHeight / 2}px`);
  this.style.setProperty('--x', `${ev.pageX - this.clientWidth / 2}px`);
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; height: 100vh; background-color: #000f; }

.wrapper {
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  font: bold 72px/100vh Arial;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff0; background-color: #ffff;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #ff0f, #ff00 2em);
  background-position: var(--x, 0px) var(--y, 0px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">BACKLIGHT</div>
```

Для нескольких вложенных текстовых элементов:

```js
document.querySelector('.wrapper').addEventListener('mousemove', function(ev) {
  this.style.setProperty('--y', `${ev.pageY - this.clientHeight / 2}px`);
  this.style.setProperty('--x', `${ev.pageX - this.clientWidth / 2}px`);
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; height: 100vh; background-color: #000f; overflow: hidden; }

.wrapper {
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  color: #fff0; background-color: #ffff;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #ff0f, #ff00 30vh);
  background-position: var(--x, 0px) var(--y, 0px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  text-align: center;
}

.title { font: bold 72px Arial; margin: .1em; }
.descr { font: bold 22px Arial; margin: .1em; }
.block { font: bold 48px Arial; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<h3 class="title">BACKLIGHT</h3>
<p class="descr">Можно добавлять <i>разные</i> текстовые элементы,<br> в рамках элемента <span class="block">wrapper</span> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли мою идею, но когда я попробовал добавить ещё один элемент с таким же классом, как у первого, у него на заднем фоне был просто статичный радиальный градиент, который не двигался с перемещениями курсора. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы: 1) был один градиент, который всегда двигался за курсором и просвечивал все текстовые элементы; 2) не было необходимости задавать специальные классы для всех текстовых элементов?

Comment: @krasmaks: дополнил вариантом. Один градиент просвечивает любые текстовые узлы, которые находятся в контейнере с общим основным классом `.wrapper`. Остальные классы добавляйте по своему желанию.

Comment: @krasmaks: да, кстати, вместо `radial-gradient()`, можно ставить `url(адрес картинки)`. Поэкспериментируйте на досуге. Удачи в творчестве))

Comment: Да, интересная задумка, обязательно проверю это позже. Спасибо за хороший ответ! P.S. Я отметил ваш ответ как принятый и полезный. Я сделал всё правильно, или мне что-то ещё нужно сделать? (я новичок, поэтому задаю глупые вопросы)

Comment: @krasmaks: если ответ действительно решает ваш вопрос, то всё правильно сделали. Я за объективные оценки. А вот вопрос нужно сопровождать, хотя бы минимальным кодом, чтобы отвечающим было от чего отталкиваться и не писать код, который наверняка у Вас уже есть (пусть даже наброски).

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо ещё раз за ваш ответ. Далее постараюсь сопровождать свои вопросы кодом.

Answer (score 2):

как то так? но заранее говорю это очень сырая версия многое надо доработать с js не проблема но лень копаться в css свойствах :)
кстати думаю в инете навалом готовых нормальных решений

```js
let shineElem = document.createElement('span')
shineElem.classList.add('shine')

let hell = document.querySelector('.halloween')
let hellText = document.querySelector('.halloween__text')

let x = hellText.getBoundingClientRect().x
let y = hellText.getBoundingClientRect().y

hell.addEventListener('mousemove',e => {
  hell.append(shineElem)
  shineElem.style.left = e.x - 25 + 'px'
  shineElem.style.top = e.y - 25 + 'px'
})
```

```css
.halloween{
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.halloween__text{
    transition: all .5s linear;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.04;
    color: white;
}

.shine{
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 100px -100px 80px rgba(255, 255, 255);
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="halloween"><h1 class="halloween__text">halloween</h1></div>
```

Comment: Да, неплохое решение, но мне нужно, чтобы градиент именно был виден только через текст, и сам текст должен быть светлым или белым.