# Просвечивание градиентом через рамку

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, border

Нужно сделать примерно как тут: [Как сделать просвечивание через текст свечением, исходящим от курсора?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1212114/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0), но чтобы градиент просвечивался через стандартную border-рамку (или какой-нибудь элемент, ее имитирующий). Вопрос в том, как же это сделать в плане стилей и структуры (что по дополнительным элементам, если они нужны). Заведомо рад любым ответам. Спасибо!

Comment: Немногим более, чем год назад, Вы говорили, что попробуете разобраться. Не видно прогресса пока... Пичалько...

Answer (score 2):

Основываясь на [связанном ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1212161/265406) - переносим все стили и манипуляции на псевдоэлемент, делаем его чуть больше (на нужную толщину рамки) и ставим позади родителя.

```js
document.querySelector('.wrapper').addEventListener('mousemove', function(ev) {
  this.style.setProperty('--y', `${ev.offsetY - this.clientHeight}px`);
  this.style.setProperty('--x', `${ev.offsetX - this.clientWidth}px`);
});
```

```css
body { display: flex; justify-content: center; background-color: #000f; }

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 20px;
  font: bold 72px/1em Arial;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ddd; background-color: #000;
}
.wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px; left: -3px; z-index: -1;
  height: calc(100% + 6px); width: calc(100% + 6px);
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: var(--x, 0) var(--y, 0) / 200% 200%
    radial-gradient(circle at center, #ff0f, #f00f, #ff00 2em) no-repeat #111;
  transition: .25s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">BACKLIGHT<br>BORDER</div>
```

Comment: а ты крут! (☞ﾟヮﾟ)☞

Comment: @MrP , спасибо. Если бы не синдром самозванца, то крутость даже применение нашла бы :)

Comment: я с ним уже 4ый год работаю. До сих пор не отпускает. Даже бросал всё это дело, и уходил преподавать гитару, лол. На деле же большинство вообще не выкупает, что происходит в it. главное быть хитрым (¬‿¬)

Comment: @MrP , согласен. Народ сейчас действует по принципу "главное ввязаться в драку, а там разберёмся". Главная беда нашего времени - невежды, лентяи и хамы.

Comment: Согласен на 100%, друг (: Удачи тебе в такое не простое время.